# Error while installing java in ubuntu 16.04 having Cyberoam Client installed

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04 OS` and also linked my pc with `Cyberoam` client for the security purpose.

I'm trying to install java for Android Studio in it and I'm getting following error in terminal :

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
>   to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   cabextract:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to
>   be installed  cryptsetup:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is
>   not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 (>= 2:1.02.24) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libgcrypt11:i386 (>= 1.4.2) but it is not installable
>                      Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.15) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: dmsetup:i386
>                      Depends: plymouth:i386 but it is not going to be installed  gettext:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                   Depends: libcroco3:i386 (>= 0.6.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libgomp1:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libncurses5:i386 (>= 5.5-5~) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libtinfo5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libunistring0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.6.27) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 (= 0.18.1.1-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed  initramfs-tools : Breaks:
>   cryptsetup:i386 (< 2:1.6.6-4~) but 2:1.1.0~rc2-1ubuntu13 is to be
>   installed  intltool-debian : Depends: gettext  libasprintf-dev :
>   Breaks: gettext:i386 (< 0.18.1.1-10)  libcapi20-3:i386 : Depends:
>   libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed 
>   libgettextpo-dev : Breaks: gettext:i386 (< 0.18.1.1-10)  libgettextpo0
>   : Breaks: gettext:i386 (< 0.18.1.1-6)  libmpg123-0:i386 : Depends:
>   libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed  libodbc1:i386
>   : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libltdl7:i386 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed  libpam-winbind:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15)
>   but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 1.1.3-2~) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libtalloc2:i386 (>= 2.0.4~git20101213) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libtdb1:i386 (>= 1.2.7+git20101214) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: winbind:i386 (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.4) but it is not going to be installed  libwbclient0 : Breaks:
>   libwbclient0:i386 (!= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but
>   2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.4 is to be installed  libwbclient0:i386 : Depends:
>   libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Breaks: libwbclient0 (!= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.4) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed  lintian : Depends:
>   gettext  lmc:i386 : Depends: libaudio2:i386 but it is not going to be
>   installed  oracle-java9-installer : Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) but
>   it is not going to be installed
>                             Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not going to be installed
>                             Recommends: oracle-java9-set-default but it is not going to be installed  samba : Depends: python-dnspython but it
>   is not going to be installed
>            Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
>            Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
>            Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
>            Depends: tdb-tools but it is not going to be installed
>            Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
>            Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
>            Recommends: attr
>            Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
>            Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed  smbclient:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is
>   not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libcomerr2:i386 (>= 1.01) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libk5crypto3:i386 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libreadline6:i386 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libtalloc2:i386 (>= 2.0.4~git20101213) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libtdb1:i386 (>= 1.2.7+git20101214) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed  ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: cabextract
>   unixodbc:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be
>   installed
>                    Depends: libreadline6:i386 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: odbcinst1debian2:i386 (>= 2.2.11-3) but it is not going to be installed  unrar:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>=
>   2.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  wine1.4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it
>   is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: binfmt-support:i386 (>= 1.1.2)
>                   Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer:i386 or
>                               kde-runtime:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                   Recommends: ttf-droid:i386 but it is not installable
>                   Recommends: ttf-liberation:i386
>                   Recommends: ttf-umefont:i386 but it is not installable
>                   Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core:i386 but it is not installable
>                   Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei:i386
>                   Recommends: winbind:i386 but it is not going to be installed  wine1.4-common : Depends: wine1.4 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1) but it
>   is not going to be installed  wine1.4-i386:i386 : Depends:
>   libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23)
>                        Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.9) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                 libgl1:i386
>                        Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                 libglu1:i386
>                        Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
>                        Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
>                        Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.26) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: liblcms1:i386 (>= 1.15-1) but it is not installable
>                        Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1:1.13) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libncurses5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                    libfontconfig:i386
>                        Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libgif4:i386 but it is not installable
>                        Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
>                        Recommends: libjpeg8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libpng12-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installable
>                        Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                        Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed  winetricks:i386 : Depends: sudo:i386 E: Unmet
>   dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a
>   solution).

How it could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search, I found the answer of problem.

Just need to follow this link and run following command in terminal.

```
dpkg -P libxapian-1.3-4 1.3.3-0ubuntu2
apt-get -f install
```

and then try to install java.

Credit goes to this post : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310561